# Wix framework: how to set SharedDllRefCount="yes" on all harvested files?

Tags: windows-installer, wix3.11

I am working with Wix3.11, Visual Studio 2019 and the Wixproj-Templates of VS2019.

I created a merge module with harvesting its files. I created a msi to install the merge module. Everything works fine.

I want to use the merge module with different msi's

My question:

I want to set the property SharedDllRefCount="yes"
(like the "Component"-object offers)
of every harvested file in the merge module
(to avoid removing the files until the last msi ist uninstalled).
How to?

Way of harvesting the files

MyMergeModule.wixproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <HarvestDirectory Include="$(HarvestSourceDirectory)" SuppressRootDirectory="true" Visible="false">
        <DirectoryRefId>TARGET_OF_HARVEST</DirectoryRefId>
        <PreprocessorVariable>var.SourceDirectoryOfMyData</PreprocessorVariable>
        <ComponentGroupName>ComponentGroup2Harvest</ComponentGroupName>
    </HarvestDirectory>
</ItemGroup>
```

MyMergeModule.wxs

```
<Module Id="MyModuleId)" ... >
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir" />
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroup2Harvest"/>
</Module>
```

Remarks: There is more code in the files, the displayed code is the relevant, I think

Or is there a possibility to add the property SharedDllRefCount="yes"
while merging in the msi?

Thanks in advance.
Have a nice day.

Comment: The SharedDllRefCount is a legacy ref-count mechanism and should not be needed for other MSI files to recognize that the file has been installed before by your same merge module (merged into a different package). The SharedDllRefCount is for non-MSI setups to do their reference counting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
What would be a practice to avoid uninstall the files in my use case? 
I is not possible to put the files of the msm into an own msi (because of the development history...)